# SQL Server Identity Column Insert Fails

Tags: sql-server

Hi guys I just have one quick question:

what happens when an insert statement fails on an identity column?

Is it possible that say for example that if I insert a row with an identity column, that identity column will be 1, and insert again but that fails and does not insert and data. Then try to insert again and that identity for that row is now 3?

Any advice will be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends on what the cause of the fail on data insert is. If for example the values are invalid (wrong types), then the identity value won't be incremented. However, if the first insert is successful, but is then removed (by a transaction failed and rolled back), then the identity value IS incremented.

```
-- Next identity value = 1
INSERT INTO Table1 (
    field1)
VALUES ('a')

-- Next identity value = 2    
BEGIN TRAN
INSERT INTO Table1 (
  field1)
VALUES ('b')

-- Next identity value = 3    
ROLLBACK TRAN

-- Next identity value = 3, although the insertion was removed.    
INSERT INTO Table1 (
  field1)
VALUES ('c')

-- Next identity value = 4
```

The first insert will have identity column value = 1, the second one fails, and the third one will have identity column value = 3.

Answer (score 1):

Just because a column has an `IDENTITY` specification doesn't necessarily mean it's unique.

If you **don't** have a unique constraint (or a primary key constraint) on that column, you can definitely insert multiple identical values into rows for that column.

Typically, though, your `IDENTITY` columns **will be** the primary key (or at least have a `UNIQUE` constraint on them) and in that case, attempting to insert a value that already exists will result in an error ("unique constraint violation" or something like that)

In order to be able to insert specific values into an `IDENTITY` column you need to have the `SET IDENTITY_INSERT (table name) ON` - otherwise, SQL Server will prevent you from even specifying values for an `IDENTITY` column.

For illustration - try this:

```
 -- create demo table, fill with values
CREATE TABLE IdentityTest (ID INT IDENTITY, SomeValue CHAR(1))

INSERT INTO IdentityTest(SomeValue) VALUES('A'), ('B'), ('C')

SELECT * FROM IdentityTest  -- Output (1)

-- insert duplicate explicit values into table
SET IDENTITY_INSERT IdentityTest ON

INSERT INTO IdentityTest(ID, SomeValue) VALUES(1, 'Z'), (2, 'Y')

SET IDENTITY_INSERT IdentityTest OFF

SELECT * FROM IdentityTest  -- Output (2)

-- add unique constraint
TRUNCATE TABLE dbo.IdentityTest

ALTER TABLE IdentityTest ADD CONSTRAINT UX_ID UNIQUE(ID)

INSERT INTO IdentityTest(SomeValue) VALUES('A'), ('B'), ('C')

SET IDENTITY_INSERT IdentityTest ON

INSERT INTO IdentityTest(ID, SomeValue) VALUES(1, 'Z')  -- error message (3)

DROP TABLE IdentityTest
```

Output (1):

```
ID  SomeValue
1   A
2   B
3   C
```

Output (2):

```
ID  SomeValue
1   A
2   B
3   C
1   Z
2   Y
```

Error Message (3):

> Msg 2627, Level 14, State 1, Line 9
>   Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint 'UX_ID'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.IdentityTest'. The duplicate key value is (1).

Answer (score 1):

One way is to prevent the insert if the row already exists.

`IF (Not Exists (Select ID From Table Where SomeCol = @SomeVal)
Insert Into Table Values (@SomeVal)`